# Is Mozilla Developer Network a valid source to cite?

Tags: citations

I'd like to cite MDN for my thesis, but since it's a wiki I'm a little afraid to cite it, although it's peer reviewed as well.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 4):

If that's where you got information you used then that is what you cite. Whether it's a reliable source of information is a question you should probably take up with your advisor.

Sometimes you can trace information found on a secondary source back to primary sources. That's often the case with wikipedia. When that's possible it's preferred.

Comment: If you cite a wiki or other potentially volatile source (i.e. most things on the web), include a date at which you retrieve the information. The page pointed to by a URL can change drastically.

Comment: @Buffy 'If you cite a wiki or other potentially volatile source (i.e. most things on the web), include a date at which you retrieve the information'... or make sure the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) has got a copy, then provide the URL for a particular dated version on there.

Comment: It cannot hurt to create a local copy as well. Zotero has a function for this, but commen browsers have a "save full page" function as well, it just saves less metadata (but may be easier to use outside of Zotero).